# Javascript Regex match string except when string starts with "

Tags: javascript, regex

I know first off that this is probably the worst looking regex ever but here goes.

I have this regex

```
(?:http://)?(?:www.)?youtu(?:be)?.(?:[a-z]){2,3}(?:[a-z/?=]+)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11})(?:[a-z0-9?&-_=]+)?
```

which is capable of matching any of these

```
www.youtu.be/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4&feature=related
http://youtu.be/QH2-TGUlwu4
http://www.youtube.com/embed/QH2-TGUlwu4
http://www.youtube.com/v/QH2-TGUlwu4?version=3&amp;hl=en_US
```

What it does in javascript is tears it apart and just returns the video code.

What I would like to happen is for it to return zero matches if the whole string starts with a double or single quote like so.

"http://youtu.be/QH2-TGUlwu4

Here is where I lose all sense of what I am doing. I know what a negative lookahead is in theory but I found this somewhere else on the site and just plugged it in thinking it would solve problems.

If i put this `^(?!\")` before it, it will return zero matches if *anything* is before the string.

Help?

Comment: Why don't you use just `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11})` to get video code? Can you post example when `"` occur in string?

Comment: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4&feature=related

Comment: The question answers itself using negative lookahead. The only problem is a bug (using `^` without realizing what it does) as pointed out in Matti's answer.

Comment: Just add a ^ at the start of your original regex then, to force it to match the http or www or youtu as the start of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `^`. It's constraining the match to the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match only if there isn't a single or double quote as the first character, you need the character class like this, `^[^'\"]` it means constrained to start, not, single or double quote.

I'll need you to clarify if you want more specifics on how to accept certain things, do you want to allow http:// but not allow "http:// ? If so, just use ^http to force the first thing in the string to be http.

Example of use to allow whatever happens to be there, except a single or double quote first letter:

```
^([^'\"].*)?http...
```

Comment: I should also mention that I'm pulling this out of a block of text much like a forum post. The `^([^'\"].*)?http...` works great but only if there is nothing before the quote.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex Gosselin said, add a `^` to the beginning of your regex to force it to start the match at the beginning of the string, making anything not matching to fail.

Some notes:

- **Escape or move the `-`** in character classes. If it is not the first/last char in the char class you need to escape it.
- Escape the `.`s.
- `(?:[a-z])` is `[a-z]`.
- `(?:x+)?` is `x*`.
- I'm guessing you want a `$` at the end of your regex as well.

Resulting in something like:

```
^(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.[a-z]{2,3}(?:[a-z/?=]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})[a-z0-9?&_=-]*$
```